# Get scheduler passed to subscribeOn() while creating Observable/Single

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Let me show a simplified example of the problem I'm struggling with:

```
class CarService {

    func getCars() -> Single<[Car]> {
        return Single.create { observer in
            // Here we're using a thread that was defined in subscribeOn().
            someCallbackToAPI { cars in
                // Here we're using main thread, because of the someCallbackToAPI implementation.
                observer(.success(cars))
            }
        }
    }
}

class CarRepository {

    func syncCars() -> Completable {
        return CarService().getCars()
            .flatMapCompletable { cars in
                // Here we're using main thread, but we want some background thread.
                saveCars(cars)
            }
    }
}

class CarViewController {

    func loadCar() {
        CarRepository().syncCars()
            .subscribeOn(someBackgroundScheduler)
            .observeOn(MainThread)
            .subscribe()
    }
}
```

From the bottom: `CarViewController` wants to sync all the cars from some external API. It defines what thread should be used for the sync with `subscribeOn` - we don't want to block the UI thread. Unfortunately, underneath, the `CarService` has to use some external library methods (`someCallbackToAPI`) that always returns the result in a main thread. The problem is that after receiving the result, all methods below like e.g. `saveCars` are called in the same main thread. `saveCars` may block the UI thread because it saves data to database. Of course I could add `observeOn` between threads between `CarService().getCars()` and `flatMapCompletable`, but I want the `CarRepository` to be dump and know nothing about the threads. It is the `CarViewController` responsibility to define working thread.

So my question is, is it a way I could get the scheduler passed in `subscribeOn` method and switch back to the scheduler after receiving the result from `someCallbackToApi`?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

As you surmise, the problem is that your `someCallbackToAPI` is routing to the main thread which is not what you wanted and there's nothing you can do about that short of re-writing someCallbackToAPI. If you are using Alamofire or Moya, I think they have alternative methods that won't call the closure on the main thread but I'm not sure. URLSession does *not* switch to the main thread so one idea would be to use it instead.

If you want the `saveCars` to happen on a background thread, you will have to use observeOn to push the computation back onto a background thread from main. The only thing `subscribeOn` will do is *call* `someCallbackToAPI(_:)` on a background thread, it cannot dictate what thread the function will call its closure on.

So something like:

```
func syncCars() -> Completable {
    return CarService().getCars()
    .observeOn(someBackgroundScheduler)
        .flatMapCompletable { cars in
            // Now this will be on the background thread.
            saveCars(cars)
    }
}
```

As a final note, an empty subscribe is a code smell. Any time you find your-self calling `.subscribe()` for anything other than testing purposes, you are likely doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the answer. From the architecture point of view, deciding on which thread the callbacks will be launched on Alamofire/Moya level is not an ideal solution. The only solution I can think of is to pass the scheduler as a parameter to `getCars` method and switch to it after the callback is launched. BTW empty `subscribe()` is just for the example.

Comment: Yes, but the underlying problem is that Alamofire performs work on a background thread, then switches to the main thread to emit the result, then you are switching back to a background thread to continue working with he result. It would be far better to never involve the main thread in the first place. If Alamofire doesn't provide a means to do it, then use URLSession which does.